# Putty title bar color

Tags: putty

I just had to change laptops and I was able to export all my putty sessions and load them onto the new laptop and everything is good.  The only change is that on the old laptop when I had numerous putty sessions opened the session that was in the forefront, or the session where I would be typing, the title bar was in blue.  It made it easy to recognize which was the active putty session.  However on the new laptop they all appear in white only.  The old putty version was .70 and this one is .75.  Just curious if this was eliminated during version updates.  The session configurations are the same, they carried over.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the above. PuTTY has always used a standard Win32 window, where the title bar's color depends entirely on your current Windows theme and not on PuTTY settings.

If you are using Windows 10, go to *Settings → Personalization → Colors* and select the option "Show accent color on: Title bars". This will make the active PuTTY window have the title bar in whichever color you have selected in the same settings page.

[image: Screenshot of the aforementioned checkbox]

(This generally won't affect UWP apps, such as Settings itself, and will have varying effects on Win32 apps which draw their own titlebars, such as Chrome or Firefox.)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly as Putty works here.  Putty is now a installation, not just a file you run, so it lives to the Windows Standards.

Comment: The corresponding Registry setting is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM` DWORD `ColorPrevalence` set to 1 -- which does not help much at my side as there is a huge difference between Dark Mode and Dark Theme.